# Get padding caused by stretch value Uniform

Tags: wpf, xaml, background, padding, imagebrush

A WPF UI element has defined a width and height, the background is set to an image brush and pointed the image source to some random images on run-time. The stretch property is not set, hence I assume it is the default value "Fill" that comes into play. Since control size and image size are different, in run-time, the background image brush is filled with some aspect ratio, i.e with a padding (visually) inside the control. Is there a way to get this padded values?

Sample code :

```
<Grid Width="2000" Height="2000">
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MyModel.Instance},Path=ImageSource,Converter={StaticResource pathImageConverter}}" />
    </ListBox.Background>
</ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Instead of image brush if I use a color, it fills the entire area.But if I use an image say 5000 * 4000 dimension, it stretches somewhat to fill inside the space (without skewing and cropping). That is not the real padding, visually we feel there is a padding from the list box boundaries and image boundaries. Let me try to get a snapshot of this.

Comment: The default value of the `Stretch`property is `Fill`. So the "padding" you see is probably not caused by the ImageBrush.

Comment: @Clemens, yes its default is "Fill".Thank you

Comment: @Clemens, my original question still stands the same.

Comment: `Fill` means to fill the entire background area. This will change the aspect ratio of the image, but won't cause any padding.

Comment: The `Padding` property is defined on Control, an `UIElement` doesn't contain those that property. Do you mean the `Image` control?

Comment: Next, do you mean that you've set the `Width`, and `Height` to a fixed value?? Maybe, it's useful to add sample xaml code to show how you've done this...

Comment: @ties, added sample code.

Comment: The ImageBrush fills the entire Background of the ListBox. You may however see a border. Probably set `BorderThickness="0"`.

Comment: @Shanadas Try using the tools I've linked to see if there is actually padding there. XAMLspy easily shows you which element (if any) have a padding set. It seems like there might be something going on with your image.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple tools to get those values, and where they are assigned when running the application:

- [XAMLSpy](http://xamlspy.com/)
- [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)

And probably more, but these are the ones I use when encountering a problem like yours.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but I am looking for some API that helps me to get these values in run-time.

Comment: These are grabbing the values in run-time.

Comment: I assume, those applications sniff dimensions by executing independently. In my case, I need to get access to these values and pass to another API for processing.

Comment: Alright, that wasn't in your question. I don't know of an easy way to get those values in run-time and pass them through to another API.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API to get those values, I'm afraid you need to do the calculations yourself. Let me elaborate...

As indicated in the comments, the `ImageBrush` is not causing your padding. The brush will simply paint the area it gets. Of course, depending on the mode of the `ImageBrush`, it won't paint the entire area, but only a portion. Changing the brush to a `SolidColorBrush` will show you the entire area the brush will get. That should be identical to the area the image brush will fill, if it's put in... well, `Fill` mode.

However, I highly doubt it's the brush, but rather the `ControlTemplate` of the `ListBox`. If you're running in the Aero theme, by default, the template starts with a `Border`, which has its `Background` property template binded back to the `ListBox`, and it does the same with the `BorderThickness` (and to make things worse, it also has a fixed padding of 1, however, the background is drawn on top of that).

So to calculate the "padding" of the brush, you need to do [the same](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Border.cs,256) as `Border` does: `BorderThickness` + `Padding`.

However, if you're running in a different theme, or if your controls have been restyled, then your control templates might be different, and the calculation might be different...